# is JWT better than Session?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, session, cookies, jwt

I wrote an API that uses JWT to authenticate the incoming requests.

I connected an ASP.NET Core application to this API. When the users login to the application, it asks the api if the credentials are goods, and if they are the api sends back a JWT token to the application.
This application finally stores the JWT to an httpOnly cookie on the client.

Now, I want to use the "User.IsAuthenticated" feature to displays the name of the actual user if he possesses a JWT cookie.

To do so, I wrote a JWTManager which analyze each requests of the application and if the user possesses a JWT cookie, the Manager will authenticates the user with HttpContext.SignInAsync by decoding the JWT, verifying his authenticity from the api then reading all the claims it contains before adding it to the User Session.

Tldr, I discuss to the api with jwt but I use cookie sessions on the application, sessions that I ironically create from jwt too.

My question is, do I need to keep sessions ?

Basically, I implemented the cookie session to use the [Authorize] annotation. But because the api already uses it, I can simply verify if the api returns unauthorized to stop the user from accessing the content he isn't authorized to use.

To display the name, I can avoid the User.Identity.IsAuthenticated and simply look for his JWT, verify if its authentic from the api then displays his name from the JWT. If he hasn't a JWT, I can display "Sign in" instead of his name.

What is the optimal way to use JWT ?

I choose it to reduce the calls to database from the api and to make the cross applications easier to use. And avoiding session will also reduce the memory used by the server to store them.

But is it worth it ? I'll ask the api if the JWT is authentic at each request from the client, then decode the JWT to at least write the username on the navigation bar to each requests (yes I can use cache and ajax to avoid reloading the navbar at each request, but I still need to verify if the user has access to the content).

Is it more efficient than just use a session with several roles and [Authorize] my content ?

Or finally my mixed use of both feature is efficient ? (Authenticate and discuss with the api from jwt will using session on the application)

Comment: Too long for a formal answer, but ideally if you use the JWT pattern, then it should be completely stateless.  That is, there should be (almost) no need to store anything on the server.

Comment: I think there are 2 layers that sit fairly tight together on the server side. The first one is like a normal web layer (which stores the sessions), the second one right before the first one (receiving the request first) is to parse the JWT token. So if your service serves non-browser clients (e.g: desktop apps, mobile apps, other servers, ...) then you can just need to remove the first layer I mentioned (so no session is stored). The second layer can be packaged for reusing or easily integrated with other layers.If your service serves browsers, it should have 2 layers integrated (as u've done)

Comment: session is better if you have much data to be kept in a session. But when using token, we usually do not need to save much data. I think using token is a bit faster. But if you really care about the difference in performance between the two, just try benchmarking it yourself. I do not think the performance here is the key point to determine which should be used over the other.